# mssql_connect() problems even with php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

So apparently I'm a lucky bastard and got problems with this function in my localhost ever since I know myself.

I can't change the connection to PDO due to the code simply isn't mine and have more than 100 files with this connection, so I have to keep them, and connect into my localhost with them, so I can edit and work on it while on my machine.

When I try to connect with `mssql_connect()` the following error is displayed: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()`

Searching on all type of questions here, I found that `mssql_connect()` doesn't work anymore on 5.3 versions + of php, but there is some .dll that Windows itself provides to those who still want to work with this function.

The .dll files are:

`php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll` and `php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll`

I'm using 54 because my php version is 5.4.45

Even though, still not working, the .dlls are enabled in `php.ini`, but the message keeps showing.

Does anyone REALLY have a solution to this problem? I really need to keep using this functions...

Thanks!

Comment: 'enabled in .ini' means nothing. you need to check if they're actually loaded. php on windows is semi-stupid, and you need to not only match versions but the compilers used to build the binaries. if you have a .dll from compiler X and your PHP was built using compiler Y, they're highly unlikely to be compatible.

Comment: So what is your opinion on how can I solve this mate?

Comment: check error logs to see what (if anything) happens when php tries to load the dlls.

Comment: have you tried `sqlsrv_connect` ?

Comment: mssql != sqlsrv.  mssql functions have been removed in PHP 7.0.